# Do you know any jquery based plugin(Free to use) plugin to implement graphs

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to implement various interactive graphs like pie, bar ,etc which on mouse hover will reveal few data about the chart

Something like http://www.highcharts.com/  , this is a jquery based paid plugin, I am looking for an open source option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Visualize plugin:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

Answer (score 0):

I have used Flot many times before, it is very simple to use and nice to look at: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

It has interactive points, multiple styles of graph, allows for view changes based on values or dates, and very light weight.

Also has a lot of very nice examples, and explanations of options for each graph type.

Comment: Is it possible to plot bar, pie and other basic charts using this

Comment: See the Examples page on the link, I know Pie charts are possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)

Comment: I saw the link but i couldn't find the examples for pie, bar, other basic graphs